# Presentation template framework with pre-built login/session handling?

Tags: django, templates

Just fishing for ideas here.

Do any of the major template presentation frameworks (such as Smarty, Django) have prebuilt login/security handling?  I want to save time on the security handling because it will consume a lot of time to worry about that.  I want to build a site from ground up but I dont really want to go so far as starting with a completed content management system like Joomla or Drupal...  thats way overkill.  I prefer Java, C#, or PHP and I want to start from as close to "scratch" as I can.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Django has a complete authentication/authorization framework - see [the docs here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/).

For registration, James Bennett's add-on project [django-registration](http://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/wiki/Home) is excellent and popular.

**Edited after comment**: Django itself supplies the mechanism for allowing admins to create user credentials, storing them in the db, validating them on login, and restricting access to areas of the site based on privileges.

django-registration provides the mechanism for a user to sign up for a username via the site, via an email with a one-time confirmation URL which sets the login up as valid. There are various other plug-in projects which provide variations on this userflow, which may be useful depending how you want your site to work.

Comment: i see. the only one that ive used is the C# login modules for Visual Studio.  it sounds like django-registration is what I need but ill start with basic Django.